# Rapidly running out of space on Catalina

Tags: icloud, catalina

I am on Catalina 10.15.6, Macbook Pro (15-inch, 2017).

I have about 55 GB of free space available. However since this morning I have noticed that this space rapidly starts to reduce at about 1 MB per second! This is without launching any application.

However when I restart my machine, the space is restored and the cycle starts all over again. By using Disk Inventory X, I have noticed that the `CloudDocs` folder keeps increasing in size, in particular the size of `client.db` and `client.db-wal` keeps going up steadily. I have no idea what these two files are. I haven't tried deleting them and not sure if I should even try doing that.
[image]

Everytime I restart my machine, the space is restored but then these two files start building up again till I get a running out of space notification. How do I arrest this problem?

Comment: I cloud is designed to download files and use some of the free space. It then purges them when needed - it’s not clear there’s a problem here other than you might want to disable iCloud for a day or three to be sure you’re OK with how it’s designed. The system caches the files and your measuring tool may be pulling them into local cache.

Comment: @bmike thanks. Considering that I have about 55 GB of free space on my machine should I really be going down to 3 GB of free space left in about a couple of hours? I will try disabling iCloud as you suggested.

Comment: What does Apple system information show. Free space isn’t important to iCloud - purgeable space is used since the system can purge it on demand. The code tries to minimize transfers, not keep tens of gigs free of cached files and temporary files. Or use a tool like Daisy Disk to check your usage. I know that doesn’t prematurely download files.

Comment: Storage under System Information shows me that my Volume Name (Macintosh HD - Data) has a total capacity of 250.69GB and currently has 35.61 GB free. I restarted the laptop this morning. This "free" space is rapidly going down

Comment: And now I'm down to just 6 GB of free space with client.db-wal` upto 48 GB in size.